# How can I handle a situation where I need to send JSON and multipart/form-data in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, http

I would like to know a simple solution for receiving  images and simple data in a single post using Spring. I am a beginner in Java so I would like to know the easy way. I've used several backend frameworks and I've encountered this problem in all of them.

I have the following problem:

I was receiving a multipart/form-data like this

```
   public CasaVenda storeCasaVendaOld(@RequestParam("dormitorios")  Integer dormitorios, @RequestParam("preco")  Double preco, @RequestParam("foto_1")   MultipartFile foto_1){
```

I receive some numbers  along with an image. This is a typical first attempt of beginner's implementation.Validate will require code to be writeen in the controller and I have to receive far more parameters than described here, so it's a bad implementation.

I thought about receiving a model

```
public CasaVenda storeCasaVenda(@Valid @RequestBody CasaVenda casa)
```

Now I can validate using annotations and so. The problem is with the file. Is there a simple solution to receive the file in one post request or should I split the process of seding the overall data and the files spareted? I mean I can make the process of the resource creation two steps, first it enters the overall data and afterwards it includes the photos.

Comment: My main problem is validation. I would like to take advantage of Spring validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty easy to define an object:

```
public class MyObject {
   private Integer dormitorios;
   private Double preco;
   ...
   getters/setters/constructors/etc.
   ... 
  // I'm not sure whether you can place a MultipartFile here as well to process image, 
  // however it doesn't make sense to validate it anyway 
}
```

Then you can use this object in the controller, it will map all the query params to the fields of the object automatically by spring:

```
public CasaVenda storeCasaVendaOld(MyObject myObject) {
}
```

Now, you can place Validation annotations inside MyObject and it will be validated, just do not use `@RequestParam` annotation before the object...